# Inconsistent PyTorch Lightning validation behaviour and checkpoints not saved

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am training a model with PyTorch Lightning and have defined the requisite `validation_step` method of my PyTorch Lightning as follows (abridging the other methods):

```py
class Tacotron2(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, cfg: DictConfig) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        # initialisation code here

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx: int) -> Tensor:  # TODO typing
        x, (mel_target, gate_target) = parse_batch(batch, device=None)
        mel_out, mel_out_postnet, gate_out, alignments = self(x)
        train_loss = loss_fn(mel_out, mel_out_postnet, gate_out, mel_target, gate_target)
        self.log("train_loss", train_loss)
        return train_loss

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx: int) -> Tensor:  # TODO typing
        x, (mel_target, gate_target) = parse_batch(batch, device=None)
        mel_out, mel_out_postnet, gate_out, alignments = self(x)
        val_loss = loss_fn(mel_out, mel_out_postnet, gate_out, mel_target, gate_target)
        self.log("val_loss", val_loss)
        return val_loss

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=self.lr, weight_decay=self.weight_decay)
        return optimizer
```

I then run training with the following checkpoint callback and call to `Trainer.fit` using [Hydra](https://hydra.cc/docs/intro/) to configure the training hyperparameters:

```py
@hydra.main(version_base=None, config_path="conf", config_name="tacotron")
def main(cfg: DictConfig):
    # create datasets, dataloaders etc.

    model = Tacotron2(cfg)

    checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
        dirpath=cfg.checkpoint_dir,
        filename="{epoch}-{step}-{val_loss:.2f}-{train_loss:.2f}",
        every_n_train_steps=cfg.iters_per_checkpoint,
        save_top_k=3,
        save_last=True,
        verbose=True,
        monitor="val_loss",
        mode="min",
    )

    mlflowlogger = MLFlowLogger(
        experiment_name=cfg.mlflow.experiment_name,
        run_name=cfg.mlflow.run_name,
        tracking_uri=cfg.mlflow.tracking_uri,
        artifact_location=cfg.mlflow.artifact_location,
    )
    mlflowlogger.log_hyperparams(OmegaConf.to_container(cfg, resolve=True))

    trainer = Trainer(
        gradient_clip_val=cfg.grad_clip_thresh,
        max_epochs=cfg.epochs,
        callbacks=[checkpoint_callback],
        logger=mlflowlogger,
        log_every_n_steps=cfg.log_every_n_steps,
    )

    trainer.fit(model=model, train_dataloaders=train_loader, val_dataloaders=val_loader, ckpt_path=cfg.checkpoint_path)
```

When I run training, I see very inconsistent behaviour from PyTorch Lightning, with the following being an example output that reports both that the monitor could not be found:

```
UserWarning: `ModelCheckpoint(monitor='val_loss')` could not find the monitored key in the returned metrics: ['train_loss', 'epoch', 'step']. HINT: Did you call `log('val_loss', value)` in the `LightningModule`?
```

only to then find and report the `val_loss` metric in a subsequent iteration:

```
Epoch 1, global step 10: 'val_loss' reached 17.83135 (best 17.83135), saving model to '/home/anil/tacotron/sushi-taco/sushi/outputs/2023-09-16/09-23-59/checkpoints/epoch=1-step=10-val_loss=17.83-train_loss=11.50.ckpt' as top 3
```

**Even more strangely, when running an identical command but passing two different datasets (one significantly larger than the other), in one case the `val_loss` metric is not found by Lightning (for the larger dataset, the above `UserWarning` is reported), but in the other case the metric is correctly tracked.**

**In the case when the `val_loss` metric is not found by the Trainer, no top-k checkpoints are saved (only `last.ckpt`).**

Is this a bug in PyTorch Lightning or am I incorrectly using the Trainer's API and PL's logging?

---

Example console output:

```
Epoch 0:  62%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████▏                                                 | 5/8 [00:19<00:11,  3.89s/it, v_num=33c0]/home/anil/miniconda3/envs/sushi/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/callbacks/model_checkpoint.py:359: UserWarning: `ModelCheckpoint(monitor='val_loss')` could not find the monitored key in the returned metrics: ['train_loss', 'epoch', 'step']. HINT: Did you call `log('val_loss', value)` in the `LightningModule`?
  warning_cache.warn(m)
Epoch 0, global step 5: 'val_loss' was not in top 3
Epoch 1:  25%|█████████████████████████████████▎                                                                                                   | 2/8 [00:04<00:14,  2.34s/it, v_num=33c0]Epoch 1, global step 10: 'val_loss' reached 17.83135 (best 17.83135), saving model to '/home/anil/tacotron/sushi-taco/sushi/outputs/2023-09-16/09-23-59/checkpoints/epoch=1-step=10-val_loss=17.83-train_loss=11.50.ckpt' as top 3
```